# About sound of non-existent channels on FM

Tags: frequency, radio-frequency, noise

Well, I have learnt about resonant frequency due to series capacitor and inductor, and how the current at resonant frequency is highest, but i am confused about the sound, which appears even when no channel has been tuned, is it noise, or randomly distributed radio waves, or something else..

And, can't we eradicate then??

Also, how radios like our phone distinguish between existing and non-existing frequencies??

And, where does this sound go on playing existing channel??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the noise between channels on the FM band, it is indeed the result of random signals coming from [a number of different sources, both natural and man-made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_noise).

Most modern radios are able to distinguish noise from actual channels, and can scan over the frequency band to let you jump directly between the channels. This is likely done by comparing the received signal to [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) - if the signal is similar to white noise, the radio ignores it.

You would probably be able to eradicate most of the noise by stepping into an appropriate [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage), which shields you from electromagnetic signals, but outside such cages there will always be some background noise in the radio signal from the previously mentioned sources.

When tuning into a channel which has an actual signal, the signal will usually be much stronger than the noise (and the noise can thus not be heard). There are also ways of [filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_reduction) out such noise.

Comment: If you have looked at a commercial FM station using a software defined radio receiver in frequency space, it is apparent how to lock onto a real station. You have all of the carrier (big peak) as well as the upper and lower side bands where the signal is. If noise is masking the carrier, you aren’t even going to see it.